# Javascript element.scrollleft can't handle decimals

Tags: javascript, html, css

Apparently nor [Element.scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) nor [Element.scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll) handle scrolling with decimals properly. Is there a work around it ?

```js
const scrRight= () => {
        const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
        const newLocal = parent.offsetWidth / 6;
            parent.scrollLeft += newLocal;

        console.log('parent.scrollright', parent.offsetWidth , parent.scrollLeft,newLocal)
    };



const scrleft = () => {
        const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
        
        const newLocal_1 = parent.offsetWidth / 6;            
            parent.scrollLeft -= newLocal_1;

        console.log('parent.scrollLeft', parent.offsetWidth , parent.scrollLeft, newLocal_1)
    };
```

```css
.parent{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 500px;
}
.parent > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 calc((1/6) * 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div> 
  <div>child </div> 
  <div>child </div> 
  <div>child </div> 
  <div>child </div> 
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div>
  <div>child </div> 
  <div>child </div> 
  <div>child </div> 
  <div>child </div> 
  <div>child </div> 
  <div>child </div>  
</div>
<button type="button"  onclick="scrleft()">&#706;</button>
<button type="button"  onclick="scrRight()">&#707;</button>
```

As you can see the scroll should update every-time with **+= 500/6 = 83.3333** but instead it updates with **+= 82.7272720336914**.

#### Edit:

Yes the decimal value is very important. Just run the example above. As you can see the cells start to be misplaced. As you reach the end of the row the cells become misplaced!

Comment: What's "properly"? What is the discrepancy between expected and actual result, and how does that affect what you're trying to implement?

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I just updated the post: The scroll should update every-time with += 500/6 = 83.3333 but instead it updates with += 83.

Comment: Yes I just gave u a small example. But in my case I'm working on a scheduler and this sometimes hide the full display of the column. I'll add borders to the example above so you can see

Comment: Does the position of 83.3333 in pixels really matter that much? Why not just round up to 84?

Comment: According to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft, `scrollLeft` only accepts integers. (with an exception for 'some' systems)

Comment: Running your snippet I see borders all the time, but I do see them 'jumping' a little when I use the arrows rather than the slider - it this the problem?

Comment: As the scrolling cannot deal with non integers it might be better to use those CSS properties which can. The flex: 0 0 16.67% is also an approximation. Also, IE has been mentioned so a more old fashioned approach might suit that better.. I've posted an answer which uses margin-left rather than any CSS scroll values.

Answer (score 2):

This is my *guess* at an answer.

When using mathematical operations to calculate position, sometimes there is a fractional component in the result. When the browser renders the border of a box it will draw that border on a pixel line at an integer position on the screen: half pixels do not exist in this context AFAIK. It must therefore use an algorithm to consistently choose which pixel to draw the border on, even if it is slightly inexact.

This means that if you move the viewport successively, applying a fractional amount each time, and neglecting to take into account the positioning of boxes according to the browser's rendering algorithm, eventually your viewport position will fall out of sync with boxes rendered within it: the viewport will then not align exactly with the box you want to scroll into view.

One solution might be to ask the browser where it has rendered the box you want to position in the viewport - this gives you the gross amount to scroll - then apply the same algorithm the browser does to this value if it contains a fractional component (I guessed at `Math.ceil` below, which works reasonably well); and scroll by this amount instead.

The following seems to work pretty well in Chromium. In FF and Safari it isn't perfect, but it's close.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector(".parent")
let leftMost = 2

const moveRight = () => {
  //grab the box you want to be left-most
  const leftMostEl = parent.querySelector(`:nth-child(${++leftMost})`)
  // ask where it is relative to the viewport
  const { left: toMove } = leftMostEl.getBoundingClientRect()
  // apply a rounding algorithm to the value, and apply the move
  parent.scrollLeft += Math.ceil(toMove)
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', moveRight)
```

```css
* {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
.parent > div {
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px gray inset;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% / 6);
}
button {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px gray inset;
  width: 160px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <script>
    [...Array(20)].forEach((_,i) => document.write(`<div>${String(++i).padStart(2, '0')}</div>`))
  </script>
</div>

<button>Move right</button>
```

Comment: I do agree that getBoundingClientRect coupled with math.ceil does work better than the other approaches. But you can still notice the cells are little misplaced. The breaking point for me is what would you do if you want to scroll left ? You will still need to subtract the child's width from the scrollLeft. But still I think I'll work on improving your solution. It's a really good start

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to do a bit of maths if you wanted to support arbitrary scrolling as well as scrolling in increments.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage [CSS Scroll Snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap) and make the browser take care of aligning things for you. You just have to make sure you scroll the minimum amount of threshold necessary to trigger it (this should be 50% + 1 but I've found it more reliable to just use 66%).

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
const children = parent.getElementsByTagName('div');

const scrRight = () => {
  parent.scrollLeft = parent.scrollLeft + children[0].offsetWidth*0.66;
};

const scrLeft = () => {
  parent.scrollLeft = parent.scrollLeft - children[0].offsetWidth*0.66;
};
```

```css
.parent{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}
.parent > div {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100%/6);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>child 1 </div>
  <div>child 2</div>
  <div>child 3</div>
  <div>child 4</div>
  <div>child 5</div>
  <div>child 6</div>
  <div>child 7</div>
  <div>child 8</div>
  <div>child 9</div>
  <div>child 10</div> 
  <div>child 11</div> 
  <div>child 12</div> 
  <div>child 13</div> 
  <div>child 14</div> 
  <div>child 15</div> 
</div>
<button type="button"  onclick="scrLeft()">&#706;</button>
<button type="button"  onclick="scrRight()">&#707;</button>
```

This perfoms very smoothly for me on FireFox, with minimal clipping of the borders on Chromium browsers - I have not tested it on mobile. Scroll Snap is pretty cutting edge stuff so consistency across browsers is not guaranteed. I have personally found it to be quite finicky to work with but this use case seems to be holding up, although you are ultimately trying to subdivide pixels so it's all down to how the individual renderer interprets that.

Comment: scroll-snap-align is not supported by IE :'(

Answer (score 0):

The fact that scrollLeft/Right only accept integers had caused a problem with moving accurately to the next element. In addition IE has been mentioned in a comment by the question setter.

There may even have been a problem with alignment due to using a % flex value to 2 decimal places.

Other CSS properties can deal with length which can be a number (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number)

> The  CSS data type represents a number, being either an integer or a number with a fractional component.

This snippet therefore goes back to an 'old fashioned' way of scrolling, using the `margin-left`property to position an intermediate div which which is 'scrolled' by having its left margin altered.

The code here is deliberately basic, for example building in the width 500px and the number of divs to show but these could be replaced with JS/CSS variables as appropriate, provided the target browsers can cope.

EDIT: the code has been changed to use CSS variables and calculate widths rather than build them in at the request of the questioner. It will not therefore now work on old browsers that do not support these features.

```js
        const grandParent = document.querySelector('.grandparent');
        const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
        const newLocal = grandParent.offsetWidth / 6;
        parent.style.width = parent.childElementCount*newLocal + 'px';
        parent.style.marginLeft = '0px';

const scrRight= () => {
  let margin = Number(parent.style.marginLeft.replace('px',''));
  if (margin > -(parent.offsetWidth - grandParent.offsetWidth)) {
    parent.style.marginLeft = (margin - newLocal) + 'px';
  }
};

const scrleft = () => {
  let margin = Number(parent.style.marginLeft.replace('px',''));
  if (margin < -newLocal) {
    parent.style.marginLeft = (margin + Number(newLocal)) + 'px';
  }            
};
```

```css
.grandparent{
  --visiblewidth: 500px; /* change this to what is required */
  max-width: 100vw; /* don't let it flow out of a narrow device width */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: var(--visiblewidth);
  position: relative;
}
.parent {
  rbox-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-style: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-x: visible;
  white-space: no-wrap;
  position: relative;
 }
.parent > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: calc( var(--visiblewidth) / 6);
  position: relative;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
<div class="parent">
  <div>child 1</div>
  <div>child 2</div>
  <div>child 3</div>
  <div>child 4</div>
  <div>child 5</div>
  <div>child 6</div>
  <div>child 7</div>
  <div>child 8</div>
  <div>child 9</div>
  <div>child 10</div> 
  <div>child 11</div> 
  <div>child 12</div> 
  <div>child 13</div> 
  <div>child 14</div> 
  <div>child 15</div>
  <div>child 16</div>
  <div>child 17</div>
  <div>child 18</div>
  <div>child 19</div>
  <div>child 20</div> 
  <div>child 21</div> 
  <div>child 22</div> 
  <div>child 23</div> 
  <div>child 24</div> 
  <div>child 25</div>  
</div>
</div>
<button type="button"  onclick="scrleft()">&#706;</button>
<button type="button"  onclick="scrRight()">&#707;</button>
```

Comment: Sorry But I'm not allowed to fix the width of the children. The application I m working on is supposed to be responsive.

Comment: Hi, yes I just used your 500px and 6 as an example taken from your code. In a real site they would be calculated in the CSS and the JS. I'll update my answer. The principle is the same.

Comment: You can fix the parent width (although it's just an example). But I'm not allowed to fix the fix of the children.

Comment: Yes, what's needed is that I use the same code as you - offsetWidth in the JS. You could also use a CSS variable to hold the visible width (500px) maybe so it'll make it even easier to change and perhaps have a min width too so it scales well on narrow devices. I was trying to create a version that would work also on old browsers but I think that has caused confusion so I'll take it out.

Comment: Answer updated so the 500px width is only set in a CSS variable (and hence easily changed) and to make the width the width of the device if it's narrow (less than the set width) and to do everything else by calculation. Took out parts that helped it run on old browsers as that was not a requirement.